# Iterate through an arraylist in jstl and sending value to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am trying to display the **video thumbnails** and **onclick** play respective video.I am sending the **images path** from a servlet to this **jsp** through an arraylist of strings.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="com.jiyodigital.RetrieveVideo.GetVideoUrlServlet" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%  
    // retrieve your list from the request, with casting 
    ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
    list = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("pathlist");
    for (String s : list)
        System.out.print("**********last step "+s);  
%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="imageurl" > 
        <img src="'/mp/'+${imageurl.get[0]}+'.png'" onclick="play('<c:out value="${imageurl.get[0]}"/>')">  
    </c:forEach> 
    <div>
        <video id="videoPlayer" controls="true"></video>
    </div>
    <script src="/SamplenProject/js/dash.all.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function play(finaloutput){
            var url = "http://192.168.5.96:8080/SamplenProject/mp/"+finaloutput+".mpd";
            var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
            var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
            player.startup();
            player.attachView(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"));
            player.attachSource(url);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code within scriplet is working ,but after that finaloutput value is coming as 'undefined'.

Comment: Try  `onclick="play('${imageurl}')">`